# Shoud I store user-identifier in keychain using sign in with apple?

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I'm implementing sign in with Apple referencing Apple's sample apple (Juice).

in Sample app, after authorize completed, save user identifier in keychain.

```swift
// For the purpose of this demo app, store the `userIdentifier` in the keychain.
self.saveUserInKeychain(userIdentifier)
```

I think, it is good solution for saving and restoring userIdentifier.

but description in code block, said it is purpose of demo app.
It's OK if i store useridentifier in keychain?

Comment: Yes , it's fine. The context of the comment is that you would probably also want to persist that identifier in your server if you have one

Comment: It's ok to save it in keychain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. Store "userIdentifier" on your server because if a user resets the device || root a device, then you will lose this info. So it's always better to store it on the server.

Comment: what would be the max size of `userIdentifier`?  for example in case I store in MySql DB, would varchar(64) be enough?